# Baseline of aligned equation

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, align

How can I fix the alignment of this equation?

```
\[\aligned
A = \aligned  \Bigg( &a \\ &b \\ &c \Bigg)  \endaligned  dt
\endaligned \]
```

Current output:

[image: Output]

Desired output:

[image: Desired output]

I know I can use a single aligned/endaligned pair to get the desired output, but I need to use multiple ones in my more complicated setting.

Comment: Have you tried to put "c" and "dt" on the same line ?
    \[\aligned
    A = \aligned  \Bigg( &a \\ &b \\ &c \Bigg) dt \endaligned  
    \endaligned \]

Comment: You're using two `aligned` environments, yet you're providing no alignment points. Is this deliberate?

Comment: The aligned environment takes an optional argument. Just use `[t] `

Comment: I did not know about the `[t]` optional argument. This solves it. Thanks

Comment: @Tohiko, btw: why are you not using the `\begin{aligned} .... \end{aligned}` syntax? IMO a lot easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\aligned
A = \!\aligned[t] \Bigg( &a \\ &b \\ &c \Bigg) dt \endaligned
\endaligned \]
\end{document}
```

> [image]